# expand tree to currently created node level in java swt

Tags: java, swt

It would be very useful to expand a JFace tree viewer in java swt as follows:

- whenever a new node is added to the tree, the tree viewer expands only the currently added node in the tree (and its children if any).
- I have used the `expandToLevel(getIndex())` method, but this does not expands the children of the currently added node if any.

Thank you in advance for any hints and for your interest.

Comment: And your question is? An example would be nice as well.

Comment: question is: any other alternative to `expandToLevel()` function, that would allow to expand the currently added node including its children (if any)?

Comment: Calling `expandToLevel(newNode, AbstractTreeViewer.ALL_LEVELS)` doesn't do it?